# .Net 4 Workflow switch activity, how to provide possible values for the cases?

Tags: workflow, workflow-foundation-4, workflow-activity

We have rehosted the Workflow (4) designer in our application. This application has a database where certain values are stored. In the rehosted designer I added the Switch activity and set the type to one of the custom objects that are stored in our database.

Is it possible to somehow provide a list of possible values to the add case value dropdown of the designer?

Regards
urk_forever

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is [NO](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wfprerelease/thread/d0b6c375-8094-474a-8bc4-0beed0d2e088)
The best thing I've managed to achieve with this issue is to implement custom Constraint for Switch< YouCustomType > activity that invalidates the Activity if unknown case was used.

Comment: Well, that kinda sucks. I have also tried implementing a custom Switch activity to do this, but I also haven't succeeded at that.